# Firebase-Android retrieve username

Tags: android, firebase

How to retrieve usernames from Firebase?

I'm new to firebase. I tried implementing solutions from various posts here as well as from firebase guide but could not figure out how to populate a (android) list with "username"s.

Here is the firebase snapshot.(I have typed though)

```
App
 users
   -<hexcode>
     -comments
      -<hexcode>
         title:"wow"
     -username
       -<hexcode>
          title:"Abc"
     -email
       -<hexcode>
          title:"abc@abc.com"

   -<hexcode>
      -comments
       -<hexcode>
         title: 
           "great"
      -username
       -<hexcode>
          title:"XYZ"
      -email
       -<hexcode>
          title:"xyz@abc.com"
```

I need to populate a list in an android app with

```
Abc
XYZ
```

Comment: Have you tried using getValue() method of the DataSnapshot ? It should return a List<User> or something like this. After that, you can loop through them and get the desired Title into new Array and populate it in your listview.

Answer (score 1):

Arrange your structure like this:

```
users
  $id1:
        name: "Abc"
        email: "abc@abc.com"
        title: "wow"
  $id2:
        name: "XYZ"
        email: "xyz@xzy.xy"
        title: "great"
```

And then use:

```
  FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  firebaseDatabase.getReference("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, User>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, User>>(){};
        HashMap<String, User> dataset = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);
        if (dataset != null) {
              for( String id : dataset.keySet)() ){
                    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview).append(dataset.get(id).getName());
              }
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      }
  });
```

And create a model class like this:

```
public class User {

    private String name;
    private String comments;
    private String title;

    public User() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

By the way, why are you using one field for a comment and a field for a title for an user?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you store the App.users within an array? and then repeat over those values to display them?

i.e get the snapshot for App.users, which should equal to an array and then you repeat over that array and display the data

If you have any further questions feel free to comment, you may need to expand your question a bit for me to give more information

Comment: The question is asking about Android, `$firebaseArray` is part of AngularFire.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just simply instantiate a `DatabaseReference`, utilize an adapter to dynamically update a Map to store your data. This way, you'll be able to store the data you need, and have it be in sync with the live database.

You need [Firecast's Video](https://youtu.be/2J6spwAVP0M). It'll help you to learn more about the Firebase Adapters.